# Why does SeaQuest only have two sub-fighters available?

Tags: seaquest

In the third season of [**SeaQuest DSV**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SeaQuest_DSV) (renamed SeaQuest 2032), the SeaQuest receives a complement of SF-1 Spectre sub-fighters due to the heightened hostility of the time. However, it seems that SeaQuest only has TWO fighters available - one piloted by Lt. Fredericksen and the other by Lt. Brody, then later by

> Mr. Piccolo after Brody's death.

**Given the frequent combat seen by the SeaQuest in Season 3, why did the flagship of the UEO only have two fighters?**

Comment: Budget cuts. It's always budget cuts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though never addressed directly in the show the most likely possibility is that only 2 can be launched at a time with an extended gap between launches to prep the next pair and then launch.  A gap that can be exploited to disable the launching mechanism in combat.

The more likely reason is CG budget, not wanting to cast additional pilots, or other development concern.